# Is there an application or some other method that would update Chromium in Windows?

Tags: updates, chromium

I like to use Chromium beside Google Chrome in both Linux and Windows. In Windows it acts like a portable program, unlike in Linux, where it can be updated automatically if desired.

I would like to be able to update Chromium automatically, or by issuing a command, running a program etc -- and not to check and download manually newer versions.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tool [chromium auto updater](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Browser-Tweak/Chromium-Auto-Updater.shtml).

You can set the time, when it should update.

But there are many other features:

> **Features**
>
> - daily update for Chromium browser at 8pm (can be changed)
> - you don't have to close browser during the update
> - you can update anytime by 'Start Menu' icon
> - does not work in the background and does not waste RAM memory
> - can be used (first use) as a Chromium Installer if browser not installed
> - you can install and use Chromium independently of Google Chrome
> - installation and uninstallation takes only 1 second

[Source](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/chromium_auto_updater.html)

[image]

To change or remove automatic download:

> - open Task Scheduler - Select task "Chromium Auto Updater by Marcin-prv" -> Properties -> Triggers

[image]

[image]

'Delete' and 'New' to create new update task, or just 'Delete' to remove automatic update.

To update instantly: under Start menu, go to **Chromium - Chromium auto updater - Update now**

Comment: This app works wrongly. It downloads smth and then I see Chromium is v51 again, whereas current version is 54.