# Chromium: profile from a newer version cannot be used: error

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, chromium

It says that my profile is from an earlier version of Chromium. It even opens 3 or 4 windows with this message:

[image]

That cannot be: I use [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/665313/162573) to constantly  update  the browser. As of today (19 June 2014) I have the latest version, which is, as far as I know, even newer than that of Google Chrome.

[image]

---

It also keeps asking me to sign in again after each restart:

---

[image]

Comment: Its possible that by using a version besides the release version you have introduced a conflict. Do you have backups of your profile?

Comment: @Ramhound - Chromium is portable and yes, I was unknowingly using different versions. The one that I was running from my pinned icons was the older one, located in a custom folder, while the one that was updating was in 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Chromium\Application'.

Answer (score 0):

That version is not the latest one in fact.

The updater was not updating that version: Chromium is portable in Windows 7 - I was using a portable one from a custom location on my hard drive. The updater had installed and was updating another version, the executable of which being `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Chromium\Application\chrome.exe`.

After running that, all profiles work as normal.

---

In fact, in order to use the [Chromium Auto Updater](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Browser-Tweak/Chromium-Auto-Updater.shtml) , one **must not change the default installation folder** - as specified in the Readme file that comes with it.